# Nested json data in js -get the values from nested array

Tags: javascript, php

Got the output result in json nested array.

Help  to access the **USER-id** of this json format .

```
var result = {
    "USER": {
        "id": "11456",
        "email": "g@gmail.com",
        "name": "g"
    },
    "status": "true",
    "group-title": "title",
    "group-name": "2-Group"
}
```

Comment: the provided json is in wrong format. Check it on http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: It should be like this `{"status":"true","USER":{"id":"11456","name":"g","email":"g@gmail.com"},
"group-name":"2-Group","group-title":"title"}`

Comment: access the userid like `console.log(result.USER.id)`

Comment: Mentioned json is in wrong format. How do you create this json. ?? Please edit your  question with proper json

Comment: Do you want to use this json in php or js

Answer (score 1):

I thin your json structue is wrong. Below is the corrected structure

```
{
  "status": "true",
  "USER": {
    "id": "11456",
    "name": "g",
    "email": "g@‌​gmail.com"
  },
  "group-name": "2-Group",
  "group-title": "title"
}
```

The json usages in **JS**

```
 var result={  "status": "true",  "USER": {    "id": "11456",    "name": "g",    "email": "g@‌​gmail.com"  },  "group-name": "2-Group",  "group-title": "title"};
resultJson=jQuery.parseJSON(result);

var userId=resultJson.USER.id; // here you will get the user id
```

Please try this way. This may help you. Don't forget to add jQuery in your script

Answer (score 0):

json values are not seperated by

```
 ;
```

the correct formate for your json is

```
var result =  {"status":"true","USER":{"id":"11456","name":"g","email":"g@gmail.com"},
                "group-name":"2-Group","group-title":"title"}
```

for this formate u can assess the user id by

```
    result.USER.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
From your code, you can directly access Id as below:

<script>
var result = {
    "USER": {
        "id": "11456",
        "email": "g@gmail.com",
        "name": "g"
    },
    "status": "true",
    "group-title": "title",
    "group-name": "2-Group"
};

alert(result.USER.id);
</script>
```